# Use parameter from function in cursor where clause and cursor rowtype

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a pl/sql function that accepts a value.  A cursor uses that value in a where clause and the function should return the first row of the cursor.

This is what I am trying to get to work.

```
create or replace package pkg_test_slot as

cursor c_test_slotis 
select * from (select person_uid, test.test, rownum r from test)
pivot(max(test) test_code for r in (1,2,3,4,5));

function f_test_getter (p_entity_uid number) return c_test_slot%rowtype;

end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
create or replace package body p_test is
  function get_rows(pll_limit in number) return sys_refcursor is
    lcur_rec sys_refcursor;
  begin
    open lcur_rec for
      select rownum rw, dum
        from (select 1 dum from dual group by cube(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
       where rownum < pll_limit;

    return lcur_rec;
  end get_rows;

  procedure prc_get_data is
    lcur sys_refcursor;
  begin
    lcur := get_rows(10);
  end prc_get_data;
end p_test;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `F_TEST_GETTER` as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_TEST_SLOT AS
  CURSOR C_TEST_SLOT(pEUID IN NUMBER) IS 
    SELECT PERSON_UID, TEST.TEST, ROWNUM R
              FROM TEST t
              WHERE t.ENTITY_UID = pEUID;

  FUNCTION F_TEST_GETTER (P_ENTITY_UID NUMBER)
    RETURN PKG_TEST_SLOT.C_TEST_SLOT%ROWTYPE;
END PKT_TEST_SLOT;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST_SLOT AS
  FUNCTION F_TEST_GETTER(P_ENTITY_UID NUMBER)
    RETURN PKG_TEST_SLOT.C_TEST_SLOT%ROWTYPE
  AS
    aRow PKG_TEST_SLOT.C_TEST_SLOT%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN
    OPEN C_TEST_SLOT(P_ENTITY_UID);

    FETCH C_TEST_SLOT INTO aRow;

    CLOSE C_TEST_SLOT;

    RETURN aRow;
  END PKG_TEST_SLOT;
END PKG_TEST_SLOT;
```

Note that I've simplified the definition of C_TEST_SLOT a bit, added the parameter, and shown how it's used in the function. Hopefully that gives you some ideas. Share and enjoy.